# How to return to multiple views a variable from an input request?

Tags: php, laravel, input, view, request

I'm building a web application and I want to edit a user profile : `Utilisateur` model in my case. A `Utilisateur` can be a `Etudiant`, a `Enseignant` or a `Partenaire`. I specified that in the models.

`Utilisateur`'s table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUtilisateursTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('utilisateurs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('fonction');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('utilisateurs');
    }
}
```

`Etudiant`'s table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEtudiantsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('etudiants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('utilisateur_id')->unique();
            $table->integer('matricule');
            $table->string('grade');
            $table->string('filiere');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('etudiants');
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm registering a user (`Utilisateur` `Etudiant` here) in the `register.blade.php` file:

```
    <form action="{{ route('createstudent') }}" method="post" oninput="username_etu.value = prenom_etu.value.toLowerCase() +'.'+ nom_etu.value.toLowerCase()" >
      @csrf
      <div class="register">
         <input type="text" Name="nom_etu" placeholder="Nom" required>
         <input type="text" Name="prenom_etu" placeholder="Prénom(s)" required>
         <input type="text" Name="username_etu" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" required>
         <input type="email" Name="mail_etu" placeholder="Email" required>
         <input id="matricule" type="text" Name="matricule" placeholder="Numéro matricule" required>

        <!-- Génération automatique du password -->
        <?php
        $random = str_shuffle('abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890!$%^&!$%^&');
        $password = substr($random, 0, 10); //Password generated
                                ?>
        <!-- Champ du password caché -->
        <input type="hidden" name="password_etu" placeholder="" value=<?php echo $password ?> /> <br>

        <select name="grade" id="grade" required>
        <option value=""><i>Cycle</i></option>
        <option value="licence" id="licence">Licence</option>
        <option value="master" id="master">Master</option>
        </select>
        <select name="filiere" id="filiere" required>
        <option value=""><i>Filière d'études</i></option>
        <option value="GL" id="GL">Génie Logiciel</option>
        <option value="SI" id="SI" class="SI">Sécurité Informatique</option>
        <option value="SIRI" id="SIRI">Systèmes d'Information et Réseaux Informatiques</option>
        </select>
        <div class="send-button">
        <input type="submit" id="submitEtudiant" value="Enregistrer">
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

I've made the password a hidden field with random value generated. Those informations will then be sent to the registered user email.

`RegisterController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\registerValidation;
use App\Utilisateur;
use App\Etudiant;
use App\Enseignant;
use App\Partenaire;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\sendUserCredentials;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    // REGISTERING A STUDENT (ETUDIANT)
    public function createStudent(Request $request){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'nom_etu' => 'required:utilisateurs,nom',
            'prenom_etu' => 'required:utilisateurs,prenom',
            'username_etu' => 'required|unique:utilisateurs,username',
            'mail_etu' => 'email|required|unique:utilisateurs,email',
            'matricule' => 'integer|required|unique:etudiants,matricule',
            'grade' => 'required:etudiants,grade',
            'filiere' => 'required:etudiants,filiere',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // echo "Errors encountered";
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);

        }
        //Fill the 'Utilisateur' table infos for a student
        $utilisateur = new Utilisateur;
        $utilisateur->fonction = 'etudiant';// Telling the user being registered is a 'etudiant'
        $utilisateur->nom = $request->input('nom_etu');
        $utilisateur->prenom = $request->input('prenom_etu');
        $utilisateur->username = $request->input('username_etu');
        $utilisateur->email = $request->input('mail_etu');
        $pass_etu = $request->input('password_etu');
        $utilisateur->password = bcrypt($pass_etu);
        $utilisateur->save();

        //Fill the specific attributes for the student registered
        $etudiant = new Etudiant;
        $etudiant->utilisateur_id = $utilisateur->id; // Link via the ids attributes the 'Utilisateur' id to the 'Etudiant' utilisateur_id;
        $etudiant->matricule = $request->input('matricule');
        $etudiant->grade = $request->input('grade');
        $etudiant->filiere = $request->input('filiere');
        $etudiant->save();

        //Once the user is created we'll send him in his mail his credentials to have access to the platform
        $data = [
            'lastname' => $utilisateur->nom, 
            'firstname' => $utilisateur->prenom,
            'usrname' => $utilisateur->username,
            'pass' => $pass_etu

        ];

        Mail::send('emails.userIds',$data, function($message) use ($utilisateur){

            $message->to($utilisateur->email, $utilisateur->username)->subject('Hi, vos identifiants pour la plateforme de gestion des projets de fin d\'études à IFRI');
        });

        $successMessage = "Utilisateur bien enregistré";


        return redirect('/register')->with($successMessage);
    }
}
```

```
        $pass_etu = $request->input('password_etu');
        $utilisateur->password = bcrypt($pass_etu);
```

As the password should be encrypted in the database, I've made it like that but still getting the randomly generated (readable) password sent to the registered user with his username.

**ISSUE**

All those work fine. I got the user registered and his credentials sent to his mail address. My issue is with the editing. I'm well getting back the data about the user `Utilisateur` whatever its profile is (`Etudiant`, `Enseignant`, `Partenaire`).

`UtilisateurController` @ `edit` function

```
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $utilisateur = Utilisateur::findOrFail($id);
        $etudiant = Etudiant::where('utilisateur_id','=', $utilisateur->id)->get();
        $enseignant = Enseignant::where('utilisateur_id','=', $utilisateur->id)->get();
        $partenaire = Partenaire::where('utilisateur_id','=', $utilisateur->id)->get();
        return view('utilisateurs.utilisateurEdit', compact('utilisateur','etudiant','enseignant','partenaire'));
    }
```

`UtilisateurEdit.blade.php`

```
<!-- Editing user -->
    <form method="PUT" action=" {{route('utilisateur.update',$utilisateur->id)}} ">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" value=" {{$utilisateur->nom}} " required> <br>
        <input type="text" name="prenom" placeholder="Prénom(s)" value=" {{$utilisateur->prenom}} " required> <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" value=" {{$utilisateur->username}} " required> <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value=" {{$utilisateur->email}} " required>
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passse" value=" {{$utilisateur->password}} " required>
        @if($utilisateur->fonction == 'etudiant')
            <!-- IF THE USER IS AN 'ETUDIANT' -->
            @foreach($etudiant as $apprenant)
            <input type="text" name="matricule" placeholder="Numéro matricule" value=" {{$apprenant->matricule}} " required>
            <select name="grade" id="grade" required>
                <option value=""><i>Cycle</i></option>
                <option id="licence" value="licence" {{$apprenant->grade == "licence"? "selected":"" }} >Licence</option>
                <option id="master" value="master" {{$apprenant->grade == "master"? "selected":"" }}>Master</option>
            </select> <br>
            <select name="filiere" id="filiere" required>
                <option value=""><i>Filière d'études</i></option>
                <option id="GL" value="GL" {{$apprenant->filiere == "GL"? "selected":"" }} >Génie Logiciel</option>
                <option id="SI" class="SI" value="SI" {{$apprenant->filiere == "SI"? "selected":"" }}>Sécurité Informatique</option>
                <option id="SIRI" value="SIRI" {{$apprenant->filiere == "SIRI"? "selected":"" }}>Systèmes d'Information et Réseaux Informatiques</option>
            </select> <br>
            @endforeach
        @endif
   </form>
```

This displays without problem the recorded attributes of the user. My issue here is that I want to display the password but the readable one : that `$pass_etu = $request->input('password_etu');` password sent to the user in his mail so that he can modify it as he wants. I don't want to use password reset.. Is there a way to get that variable as a global one and display it in my view ?

**EDIT**

I get that for some security purposes I must not try to retrieve inside the app the password (as a readable one). I've already figured out how I may get done what I wanted with the credentials not exposed and the user's session security safe I guess.

However I want to come back to that question.. *How to return to multiple views a variable from an input request?* **Is there actually a way to get an input data from a specific form for example in a view and make that data available within all other views?** As per documentation we can [share data to all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) using either AppServiceProvider or view Composers. But I think (I may be wrong..) this is with some 'preset' data that we want to be shared within some views.. Is it possible to actually get an incoming request data from the user for example and share it to all views  (**database records excepted**). I'm not in the need for that.. yet but maybe this case will occurs somehow. For what it worths if you have any idea of how this can be done, it would be nice sharing it

Comment: Am I right in thinking that when you are editing the user you want to be able to see the password in plain text?

Comment: Don't display user's password, never. It's hashed into your DB, you can't retrieve it. Let the field empty, so the user can override it if he wants, or let the current one. But please, don't post all your code for a small problem.

Comment: @VincentDecaux alright got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would avoid this entirely.

You should never display the users password in plain text. Using Laravel you are unable to (by default), it goes through a one-way hash when storing the value in the database. This means that it can't be returned back to a "readable" format.

If you absolutely did want to do this you would need to override how Laravel's authentication works and rather than hashing the password you would need to encrypt the password.

Encrypting the passwords is really not recommended. If someone gets the key they can decrypt all users passwords. It also means that you have the ability to decrypt and view users passwords - which you shouldn't be able to do.

I would also recommend avoiding sending an email to the user containing their password, personally.

Comment: ```Encrypting the passwords is really not recommended. If someone gets the key they can decrypt all users passwords. It also means that you have the ability to decrypt and view users passwords - which you shouldn't be able to do.``` Does the `bcrypt()` function I used is included?.. It may sound as a noob question but I think I saw that function inside the Laravel default authentication files, does it mean that the key of Laravel default auth system encryption can be found and all the passwords then decrypted?..

Comment: @TedAaron not quite. Bcrypt is a hashing algorithm not an encryption/decryption algorithm. For Laravel, the APP_KEY is used for encryption and decryption - not for password hashing.

Comment: Alright @George Hanson, sorry for the late answer.. Thank you for the clarification